# Страница не успевает прогрузиться перед скриншотом

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Делаю парсинг биржи с использованием selenium webdriver. Хочу сделать скриншот 15 минутки, но когда я его делаю, у меня получается дневной скриншот[image: Скриншот который делает Selenium]

Мой код P.S. Пробовал по разному и просто ожидание и через ожидания которые нашел в интернете.

```
#Import's
from selenium import webdriver
import os, shutil, glob
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys



# CODE  
def Parser(CoinName, Min_15, Min_30, Min_60):
    # Driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("https://ru.tradingview.com/")
    driver.maximize_window()

    # Looking for an input field
    Find_Element_EntryField = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='searchBar-3MXIiLE- js-header-search-button']")
    Find_Element_EntryField.click()
    
    # Entering the name of the coin
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Символ, например, SBER']"))).send_keys(CoinName + Keys.ENTER)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)       

    # Search for 15 minutes
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='header-toolbar-intervals']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-value='15']"))).click()

    # Screenshoot
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "html")))
    driver.save_screenshot("Min_15.png")
    

# Main
def main():
    with open (r'C:\Users\gogis\Desktop\фьючи\Python\Temp\tmp.txt', 'r') as f:
        CoinName = f.readline()
        Min_15 = f.readline()
        Min_30 = f.readline()
        Min_60 = f.readline()


    # Parser
    Parser(CoinName, Min_15, Min_30, Min_60)
  
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Не по теме вопроса, но у Binance есть API

Comment: Хочу научиться самостоятельно парсить, а потом уже браться за подобные инструменты

Comment: [Хочу забить гвоздь микроскопом, а потом уже браться за молоток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/339283)

Comment: Почему бы и нет)